org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 0 errors
Can any one help with this problem?
I cant configure validation in spring project .
Entity class
import javax.validation.constraints.*;

public class Employee {
    @Size(min = 2,message = "Name must be minimum 2 symbols")
    private String name;

    @NotEmpty(message = "surname is required field")
    private String surname;
}

i'm not sure is imports correct .
Controller class
import javax.validation.Valid;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class MyController {

@RequestMapping("/showDetails")
    public String showDetails(
            @ModelAttribute("employee") @Valid Employee employee,
            BindingResult bindingResult, Errors errors){

     
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){   // bindingResult.hasErrors() always return false
            return "ask-detail-view";
        }else{
            return "show-detail-view";
        }

    }
}

pom.xml
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
      <version>8.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

jsp page

<from:form action="showDetails" modelAttribute="employee">
    Name<form:input path="name"/>
    <form:errors path="name" />
    <br>
    <br>
    Surname<form:input path="surname"/>
    <form:errors path="surname" />
    <input type="submit">
</from:form>


How can i configure it correctly?

the code seems fine, the issue might be between Spring, JDK, Tomcat, and Validator versions.

Which Spring version are you using? Are you using Spring Boot or plain Spring?

spring-core version:6.1.10

The @Valid annotation already provides a corresponding response. So if you don't need the exact error in the function, this should be sufficient.

Yes. But it does't working . Because  bindingResult.hasErrors() always return false

Is it possible that you may use wrong imports for @NotEmpty and @Size?

maybe , but i have changed imports a lot
